# How do I make skeletons strong without using magic?

Tags: biology, combat, skeletons, fight

Skellies are just parasites that take over the bones of the deceased and use them like a mecha/gundam. A stick-insect but in the shape of a human, and made out of bone.
the skeleton of the heaviest, tallest, fattest, strongest , bigest and most enourmous human probably weights less than 20 kg. Even a scrawny kid can throw a 20kg weight without much effort.

is there any way to make a skeleton foe to be anything but ridiculous? Maybe even menacing? Probably I' should start by changing the name from  "skellies" to something else, but that's for another day.

> A skeleton that is literally just bone has no connective tissue holding it together, nor any muscles that can cause it to move. I struggle to imagine what this parasite looks like, it sounds like it's pretty much already using magic to animate the skeleton, as it doesn't add any mass or actually replace any of the elements that allow a person's skeleton to move in the first place.

the parasite is like a rooting system that connects the bones, the same way broken or cut bones are medically re-connected using nails along the height of the bone inside the hollow part. but not made of metal...it's just like rooty material, something biological

like in the image but not made of metal and going throu the entire skeleton.
[image]

Comment: A skeleton that is literally just bone has no connective tissue holding it together, nor any muscles that can cause it to move. I struggle to imagine what this parasite looks like, it sounds like it's pretty much already using magic to animate the skeleton, as it doesn't add any mass or actually replace any of the elements that allow a person's skeleton to move in the first place.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie the parasite is  like a rooting system that connects the bones, the same way broken or cut bones are medically re-connected using nails along the height of the bone inside the hollow part. but not made of metal...it's just like rooty material, something biological

Comment: So your question got closed as a duplicate of another one. I advise you to look at the linked question, see if it answers your needs, then either move forward if you find the answers there satisfying... Or edit your question in case you're still hungry for more bones to chew. To reopen your question, you'll have to clearly state why the other question doesn't answer yours fundamentally (i.e. on the tactical level. Small changes in anatomy won't be enough :) ).